# What's the difference b/w foldLeft and Java collect

Tags: java, scala, java-stream, vavr

This question is targeted to [Vavr](https://www.vavr.io/) (Java's FP library), but could probably apply to Scala or other FP languages that can compare to Java.

What's the difference between Vavr `foldLeft`:

- ```java
   <U> U foldLeft(U zero,
                  BiFunction<? super U, ? super T, ? extends U> combiner)
  ```

and Java's `collect`:

- ```java
  <R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
                BiConsumer<R, ? super T> accumulator,
                BiConsumer<R, R> combiner)
  ```

It seems both can achieve the same purpose: Transform a collection (say `Stream<T>`) by traversing it and accumulating a result into a new type `U` (or `R`) while traversing.

At first sight, signatures differ in #arguments, and Java `collect` seems to be intended to be run in parallel chunks.

**Which are the actual differences conceptually?** Vavr `foldLeft` seems easier to use.

Very dumb example just to illustrate:

Vavr `foldLeft`:

```java
// result = "HelloFunctionalWorld"
String result = Seq("Hello", "Functional", "World")
    .foldLeft(new StringBuilder(), (acc, word) -> acc.append(word))
    .toString();
```

Java `collect`:

```java
// result = "HelloFunctionalWorld"
final String result = Arrays.asList("Hello", "Functional", "World").stream()
    .collect(
        StringBuilder::new,
        (acc, word) -> acc.append(word),
        StringBuilder::append
    )
    .toString();
```

Comment: Hi @NathanHughes, I think I should introduce the Java `reduce` operation in the question, as I can't either see the difference b/w `reduce` and `collect` for the particular dumb example.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think factorials make for a better toy example here, e.g., https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ZxkWbgeRTaa0MbhrOGmG5Q

Comment: @user, there is a version of `reduce` that reduces to a different type `U`, so the type of the stream and the type of the reduced value can be different. They're not required to be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which are the actual differences conceptually?

As the javadoc of [`collect(Supplier<R> supplier, BiConsumer<R,? super T> accumulator, BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) says:

> Performs a [**mutable reduction**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) operation on the elements of this stream. A mutable reduction is one in which the reduced value is a mutable result container, such as an `ArrayList`, and elements are incorporated by updating the state of the result rather than by replacing the result. This produces a result equivalent to:
>
> ```java
> R result = supplier.get();
> for (T element : this stream)
>     accumulator.accept(result, element);
> return result;
> ```

The key phrase here is **mutable**, since Vavr doesn't do anything mutable, being a functional library.

The example in the question using `StringBuilder` is actually a violation of the functional principles. Why use Vavr if you don't intend to follow the functional paradigms?

---

The Java Stream equivalent of [`foldLeft()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/latest/io/vavr/collection/Traversable.html#foldLeft(U,java.util.function.BiFunction)) is [`reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), and you're correct, the 3rd parameter is to support parallel processing:

```java
// Vavr
<U> U foldLeft​(U zero,
               BiFunction<? super U,​? super T,​? extends U> combine)

// Java Stream
<U> U reduce(U identity,
             BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator,
             BinaryOperator<U> combiner)
```

If the result type is the same as the stream element type, you would be using the following alternatives, which don't need a 3rd parameter for parallel processing support:

```java
// Vavr
T fold​(T zero,
       BiFunction<? super T,​? super T,​? extends T> combine)

// Java Stream
T reduce(T identity,
         BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)
```

---

**UPDATE** Comparison of the methods:

*Vavr*

- [`T fold​(T zero, BiFunction<? super T,​? super T,​? extends T> combine)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/latest/io/vavr/collection/Traversable.html#fold(T,java.util.function.BiFunction))

  Applies `combine` in arbitrary order, so it must be an *associative* function.

  Equivalent to [`reduce(identity, accumulator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-).
- [`<U> U foldLeft​(U zero, BiFunction<? super U,​? super T,​? extends U> combine)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/latest/io/vavr/collection/Traversable.html#foldLeft(U,java.util.function.BiFunction))

  Applies values from left-to-right.

  Equivalent to [`reduce(identity, accumulator, combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) in *sequential mode*, where `combiner` is unused. *Parallel mode* supported with a valid `combiner` function.
- [`<U> U foldRight​(U zero, java.util.function.BiFunction<? super T,​? super U,​? extends U> combine)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/latest/io/vavr/collection/Traversable.html#foldRight(U,java.util.function.BiFunction))

  Applies values from right-to-left.

  No Java Stream equivalent.

*Java Stream*

- [`Optional<T> reduce(BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)

  Applies `accumulator` in arbitrary order, so it must be an *associative* function. E.g. streaming `1,2,3,4` with `+` could be processed as `((1+2)+3)+4` *(sequential mode)*, or `(1+2)+(3+4)`, `1+((2+3)+4)` or any order combination *(parallel mode)*.

  No Vavr equivalent.
- [`T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)

  Applies `accumulator` in arbitrary order, so it must be an *associative* function. E.g. streaming `1,2,3,4` with `0` and `+` could be processed as `(((0+1)+2)+3)+4` *(sequential mode)*, or `((0+1)+2) + ((0+3)+4)` or any order combination *(parallel mode)*.

  Equivalent to [`fold​(zero, combine)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/latest/io/vavr/collection/Traversable.html#fold(T,java.util.function.BiFunction)).
- [`<U> U reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)

  Applies values in order, with `combiner` providing support for parallel processing.

  *Sequential mode* is equivalent to [foldLeft​(zero, combine)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/latest/io/vavr/collection/Traversable.html#foldLeft(U,java.util.function.BiFunction)).
- [`<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier, BiConsumer<R,? super T> accumulator, BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)

  In *sequential* mode, `supplier` is used to create a **mutable** result container, and values are then applied in order. In *parallel mode*, multiple mutable result containers are created and filled with values, and are then merged using the `combiner` function.

  No Vavr equivalent.

Comment: Thanks @andreas I see the point of immutability in the accumulator. Maybe I should change the original question to compare Vavr `foldLeft` with Java `reduce`.

Comment: @GerardBosch Other than the 3rd parameter, there is no conceptual difference between `foldLeft`/`fold` and `reduce`, so what would your new question be asking? And please don't change the question to ask something different. If you want to ask something else, create a new question.

Comment: _"Why use Vavr if you don't intend to follow the functional paradigms?"_ is really funny how people that do not understand functional programming believe that a simple, local, encapsulated mutation breaks any functional code. Building strings in the JVM is extremely expensive a local string builder is totally ok even on pure code.

Comment: @user In what way is `foldLeft` and `reduce` not the same, other than the 3rd parameter already mentioned in the answer? Yes, I agree that `foldRight` is slightly different, and I've never said otherwise, given that I never said anything about it.

Comment: I think I get the subtle difference b/w `collect` and `reduce`: The mutable reduction, right? `collect` takes a `Biconsumer` (so mutates the accumulator), while `reduce` takes a `BiFunction` leading to a new accumulator instance each time (which makes sense in the context of persistent data structures for example). So finally, I guess the difference with `foldLeft` is that the later is not intended to be run in concurrent chunks and the order is guaranteed to be sequential. Is that correct?

Comment: @user *"`reduce` doesn't guarantee order"* Sure it does. Why do you believe it doesn't?

Comment: @user Why would subtraction work weird with `reduce`? If input is a stream with `1, 3, 7`, then result is `zero - 1 - 3 - 7` *(foldLeft)* or `identity - 1 - 3 - 7` *(reduce)*. Nothing weird there. With an appropriately written combiner method, `reduce` can even do it in parallel, which `foldLeft` can't. For *subtraction* operation, `zero`/`identify` is `0`, so the parallel result `combiner` is the *addition* operation: `reduce(0, (a,b) -> a - b, (a,b) -> a + b)`

Comment: My bad. I didn't know the specification also talked about order being preserved.